# Configure ZF2 route to allow only post requests

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I configure Zend Framework 2 route to only to allow `POST` request type?

I've gone through the documentation but no avail.

**EDIT**

Here is the portion of my DI code

```
'cv-create' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/profile/cv/:type/create',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\ProfileController',
            'action'     => 'cv_create',
        ),
    ),
),
```

My actual question is, is there any way to inject the request control as a constraint to this route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend the `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment` class and create a slightly modified version of `match()`. Since `match()` has the `$request` parameter it should be as simple as follows:

```
public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
{
    if (!$request->isPost())
    {
        return null;    
    }

    return parent::match($request, $pathOffset);
}
```

Then use this modified class instead of the standard Segment in the routing configuration.

Comment: As far as I know the Router just iterates over the attached routes looking for a match by calling match(). The logic for matching a route seems to sit within the Route classes such as Segment. I think the solution I have suggested is clean – an alternative mechanism would be to define a ‘route’ event in the module class – then do some checks on the matched route, i.e. route name and request type.

Comment: Why not use the built in route Zend\Mvc\Router\Route\Method o.0?

Comment: That looks promising, it’s not a class I’ve come across before and my searches yielded nothing that matched verb checking, so thanks for sharing. So I’m assuming to achieve the desired route as outlined in the question you would set up a Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Method (correct class name) then set-up a child route to match the type parameter?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be to use the AbstractRestfulController in this case.

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Mvc.Controller.AbstractRestfulController.html

Only implement the create() method.

Answer (score -1):

in class Zend_Controller_Request_Http

You can disable the other request type .

Comment: It would make for a better answer if you explained how to disable the other request type, possibly with an example.

Comment: And is this for ZF2? The underscores make me think of ZF1.